# Quel est le nom pour deux mots qui commencent par le même son

Tags: terminologie, rime

Si deux mots qui se terminent par le même son (mach**ine**, tart**ine**) sont une *rime*. Quel est le mot pour en décrire deux qui commencent par le même son (**tra**vail, **tra**cteur) ?

Answer (score 2):

[Antérime](http://oulipo.net/fr/contraintes/anterime) pourrait convenir mais ne se rapporte qu'à des vers et non des mots pris individuellement.

Answer (score 1):

L'[allitération](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allit%C3%A9ration) "consiste en la répétition d'une ou plusieurs consonnes ... à l'attaque des syllabes accentuées". L'[assonance](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assonance) "consiste en la répétition d'un même son vocalique" (le noyau de la syllabe). La rime commence avec un noyau + le coda d'une syllabe accentuée.

Je ne suis pas certain s'il existe encore un autre terme qui rapporte justement à la répétition d'attaque + noyau. Comme on l'a déjà dit, il y a "antérime", mais je n'ai pas pu trouver beaucoup sur ce terme pour vérifier s'il ait à voir avec la rime des débuts des mots en général or seulement des débuts des *vers* entiers. Cependant, voici [une ressource](http://www.ecrivantschanteurs.com/pages/article16.htm) qui affirme le premier.